# Notepad++ tries to open everything in current folder when editing new file from Total commander

Tags: notepad++, total-commander

In Total commander, I have Notepad++ associated as text editor (instead of regular Windows notepad). When I try to edit new file in Total Commander using this hotkey:

```
SHIFT+F4 Create new text file and load into editor
```

Notepad++ opens (in addition to my new file) everything else that is in the current folder (and its subfolders). Which often means it will get stuck for a while, since it tries to open every huge file as plain text.

**Here is the catch**: it does that only when my file's name does not have an extension. For example, when Total commander asks for filename (after I press Shift+F4), I don't enter "name.txt", but only "name".

How can I prevent this? I want only my new file to be opened regardless of its naming.

Total Commander version: 9.22a 64bit,
Notepad++ version: 7.8.5 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Go to Total commander Settings->Edit/View and "%1" after the path.
Example:

> c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%1"

Comment: It's already there, so that was probably not the cause. Anyway, this issue went away after I updated Notepad++ to its newest version (7.9.1).

Comment: It worked for me in two different computers :)